# SQL Server dynamic sorting on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

I have a stored procedure which uses dynamic sorting, 2 parameters determine the sorting - column: `@SortIndex` and sort direction: `@SortDirection`

relevant code:

```
...
ROW_NUMBER() OVER
            (
            ORDER BY
            --  string order by
            CASE @SortDirection
                  WHEN 'ASC'  THEN
                    CASE @SortIndex
                      WHEN 1 THEN SKU
                      WHEN 2 THEN BrandName
                      WHEN 3 THEN ItemName
                    END            
                END ASC,
                CASE @SortDirection
                  WHEN 'DESC' THEN
                    CASE @SortIndex
                      WHEN 1 THEN SKU
                      WHEN 2 THEN BrandName
                      WHEN 3 THEN ItemName
                    END
                END DESC,
```

This sorts on single columns, but I want to sort on `BrandName ASC, ItemName ASC` when `@SortIndex` is 2.

Comment: I'd recommend Dynamic SQL (building up the query in a string and executing it). The complex sorting can quickly cause many CASE structures to cover it.

Comment: Have you tried Brandname + ItemName in the When 2 clause?

Comment: Be careful if you go this path. You have strings that look like parameters. You need to be careful about sql injection and use parameterized dynamic sql.

Comment: @KevinCook - I'm slightly embarrassed to report that your solution was basically correct! All I had to do was add `WHEN 2 THEN BrandName + ',' + ItemName` and it worked.  If you want to flesh out your comment & add it as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER
            (
            ORDER BY
            --  string order by
            CASE @SortDirection
                  WHEN 'ASC'  THEN
                    CASE @SortIndex
                      WHEN 1 THEN SKU
                      WHEN 2 THEN BrandName + ',' + ItemName 
                      WHEN 3 THEN ItemName
                    END            
                END ASC,
                CASE @SortDirection
                  WHEN 'DESC' THEN
                    CASE @SortIndex
                      WHEN 1 THEN SKU
                      WHEN 2 THEN BrandName + ',' + ItemName
                      WHEN 3 THEN ItemName
                    END
                END DESC,
```

Use Brandname + ItemName in the When 2 Clause and to have both fields be used in the sort.

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot use Dynamic SQL, the only way is to list all the possible combination for `ASC` and `DESC`

For example:

```
ORDER By
CASE WHEN @SortIndex = '1' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN SKU END,
CASE WHEN @SortIndex = '1' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN SKU END DESC,
CASE WHEN @SortIndex = '2' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN BrandName END,
CASE WHEN @SortIndex = '2' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN BrandName END DESC,
--and so on...
```

Answer (score -2):

A sample for generality....By K.AryaeeMoeen

```
---------------------------------------------------
SELECT 1 AS Num, '2015-06-22' AS Datex INTO Arya
INSERT INTO Arya 
SELECT 2, '2015-08-17' UNION SELECT 3, '2015-07-14'
---------------------------------------------------
Now, Dynamic sorting(Base on Datex Field) in a SELECTION ....
---------------------------------------------------
SELECT Num, Date1 FROM ARYA, (SELECT -1 as e union Select 1 as e) a
WHERE a.e=-1  --(OR a.e=1) For Dynamic Sort
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(DAY, '2000-01-01', Arya.Datex)*sign(a.e)
---------------------------------------------------
```