# Oracle convertion to sql for DECODE

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-server-2014

Hi all I have query in oracle as follows

```
DECLARE in_variable Varchar;
Select Row_Number()
OVER
(
   Order By
   Decode(in_variable,'column_name ASC',t.column_name) Asc) b
   From table t
```

Converted to sql server as follows

```
DECLARE @in_variable NVARCHAR(100)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                (
                    ORDER BY 
                    IIF ( @in_sort_by <> '', 'column_name ASC', t.column_name ) ASC )
                    FROM                table  t
```

Is it the correct one or am I doing wrong when I give the value for `@in_variable` I am getting conversion exception in sql so can some one help me

Comment: "SQL" refers to the standard implemented by most relational databases. "SQL Server" is Microsoft's relational database.

Comment: How about validating abd verifying the results by yourself? It would save time for you as well as others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using either `DECODE` or `IIF`, you'd be better of using `CASE`. For SQL Server, this would be:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                 (  ORDER BY 
                    CASE WHEN @in_sort_by <> '' 
                         THEN 'column_name ASC' 
                         ELSE t.column_name END ASC )
FROM  table  t
```

---

If you're getting a type conversion error, that would imply that `t.column_name` is an `int`. SQL Server will try to convert the static string `'column_name ASC'` to match the data type of the column it is being used in place of. To fix this, you can try using `CAST` to convert the column to `VARCHAR`:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                 (  ORDER BY 
                    CASE WHEN @in_sort_by <> '' 
                         THEN 'column_name ASC' 
                         ELSE CAST(t.column_name as varchar) END ASC )
FROM  table  t
```

However, I think you're probably pursuing the wrong solution here. It looks like you're trying to make the analytic function sort differently based on the variable provided. Providing the alternate column name and sort order as a string is not going to do that. You should probably look questions related to [dynamic sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916384/sql-server-dynamic-sorting-on-multiple-columns) for how to do this correctly.

Comment: but this is giving me an conversion failed `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'column_name ASC' to data type int.
`

Comment: Thanks Allan I made it with `IIF` instead of `CASE`